# How to predicate an array using particular key

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

I just wanted to predicate my array with Product_Id. I tried like this

```
NSPredicate *pred=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"\"Product_Id\" ==%d",[[[_result valueForKey:@"Product_Id"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] integerValue]];
predicatedArray = [_likesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

`_likesArray` has below array of dictionary

```
(
{
    DeviceLikeStatus = 1;
    Msg = "";
    ProductCount = 1;
    "Product_Id" = 116;
}
)
```

And it is not predicating anything, always showing `predicateArray` is empty.

Comment: use "Product_Id" instead of "\"Product_Id\"

Answer (score 2):

No need of " in the predicate 
try

```
NSPredicate *pred=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Product_Id ==%d",[[[_result valueForKey:@"Product_Id"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] integerValue]];
```